# ggplot2 and geom_ribbon: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Freq' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, poisson

I am running Poisson generalized linear models on my count data, and plotting data and the fitted model with ggplot.

My data:

```
structure(list(YR = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 
1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), Freq = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
10L, 12L, 14L, 2L, 16L, 15L)), .Names = c("YR", "Freq"), row.names = 58:114, class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the script, first the model, the parameters and the plot using geom_ribbon:

```
mod <- glm(Freq~YR, data = sub9, family = "poisson")

pred.df <- data.frame(YR = seq(min(sub9$YR), max(sub9$YR), length.out = 100))
pred <- predict(mod, newdata = pred.df, se.fit = TRUE)
pred.df$count <- exp(pred$fit)
pred.df$countmin <- exp(pred$fit - 2 * pred$se.fit)
pred.df$countmax <- exp(pred$fit + 2 * pred$se.fit)

ggplot(sub9,aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,75),breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2018),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,
                                              1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,
                                              2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = pred.df, aes(ymin = countmin, ymax = countmax), alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(data = pred.df) +
  xlab(" ") + ylab("Count")
```

After first having successfully run this procedure on one data set, I get an error message when trying the same procedure with a new and similar data set. Error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Freq' not found
```

The only thing I have done is to replace the name of the data frame and changed the name of the dependent variable from "count" to "Freq", in accordance with the data frame. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (you need to specify `y` as `count` in the `aes`):

```
ggplot(sub9,aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,75),breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2018),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,
                                                  1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,
                                                  2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = pred.df, aes(y=count, ymin = countmin, ymax = countmax), alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(data = pred.df,aes(x=YR,y=count)) +
  xlab(" ") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have df and pred.df conflict. using `ggplot()` may give you what you want:

```
ggplot() +  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + geom_ribbon(data = pred.df, aes(x=YR,ymin = countmin, ymax = countmax)) + geom_line(data = pred.df, aes(x=YR,y= count))+ xlab(" ") + ylab("Count")+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,75),breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),expand=c(0,0)) +scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2018),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015))
```

[image]